# Questions about Ajax syntax and calling data from SQL database

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, database

Basically, repurpose a homework problem so it uses Ajax to call data from SQL database called Club. Opted to use a shorthand method w/ $.get(url[,data][,success][,dataType]), but textbook doesn't explain, for example, what the "success" thing is supposed to be. Like, supposed to be a data from the file? Do I need to write in a function for the dataType?

Another is it's not clear where the SQL code should go. I have a JS and PHP, but never worked w/ SQL before. Isn't it supposed to go in the SQL database? If not, where?

The JavaScript:

```
    // Initialize the object:
    var ajax = false;

    // Choose object type based upon what's supported:
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        // IE 7, Mozilla, Safari, Firefox, Opera, most browsers:
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Older IE browsers

        // Create type Msxml2.XMLHTTP, if possible:
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) { // Create the older type instead:
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) { }
        }

    } // End of main IF-ELSE IF.

    // Return the value:
    return ajax;

}
```

PHP file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Inventory</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Branch Inventory</h1>
        <?php
            $branchid = 0;
            $branchid = (int) $_GET['branchid'];
            if ($branchid > 0) {
                require_once ('dbtest.php');
                //echo 'Branch = ' .$branchid. ' returned.</p>';
                $query = "SELECT * FROM Branch WHERE Branch_Number = $branchid ";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
                echo "<p>Branch #: " .$row['Branch_Number']. "<br>";
                echo "Branch Name: " .$row['Branch_Name']. "<br>";
                echo "Location: " .$row['Branch_Location']. "<br></p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>Branch not on file.</p>";
                }
                //table for inventory
                echo "<table border='1'>";
                echo "<caption>Current Inventory</caption>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Book Cd</th>";
                echo "<th>Title</th>";
                echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $query2 = "SELECT invent.book_code As BookCd, book_title as Title,Units_on_hand As Qty 
                    FROM invent, book 
                    WHERE book.book_code = invent.book_code and branch_number = $branchid";
                $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['BookCd']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['Title']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['Qty']. "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";

            } else {
                echo '<p>No Branch ID from form.</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, the SQL (edited to show only the coding, not data):

```
CREATE DATABASE CLUB;
USE CLUB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblMembers;
CREATE TABLE tblMembers (
  MemID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  LastName VARCHAR(30),
  FirstName VARCHAR(30),
  MiddleName VARCHAR(15),
  Status VARCHAR(1),
  MemDt DATE,
  YTD_Total DOUBLE,
  YTD_Total_Dt DOUBLE,
  Password INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(MemID) 
);

INSERT INTO tblMembers VALUES

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblCodes;
CREATE TABLE tblCodes (
   TransCd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
   TransType VARCHAR(1),
   TransDesc VARCHAR(50),

   PRIMARY KEY(TransCd)
);

INSERT INTO tblCodes VALUES 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblPurchases; 
CREATE TABLE tblPurchases (
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   MemId VARCHAR(4),
   PurchaseDt DATE,
   TransType VARCHAR(1),
   TransCd VARCHAR(2),
   Amount DOUBLE,

   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

INSERT INTO tblPurchases (MemID, PurchaseDt, TransType, TransCd, Amount) VALUES
```

The two-screen application will allow the user to select a member from a drop-down list, and then press ‘go’ in order to see all transactions on file for that member. Note that the entries in this drop-down list are read from the tblMembers table of the Club database.  The code value assigned to each drop-down entry is the Member ID for the member.

When the GO button is pressed the selection page should submit itself to another PHP page.  This second PHP page will run SQL queries against the database in order to pull both the full member information (from tblMembers) and also the transaction data for that member from the tblPurchases table.

The SQL for the main page is just a simple select of all records in tblMembers returned in name order:

```
        SELECT * FROM tblMembers ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, MiddleName;
```

Then, in the top part of the second page, you select the specific member chosen by the user for review; thus, the SQL for that operation is:

```
        SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE MemID = ‘member id’
```

Note that the above ‘member id’ value shown must be replaced by the actual member ID that is the value entry of the selected drop-down entry from the first page.  However, because the member id in the database is alphanumeric, you must have the single apostrophes around it (as shown above).  So a sample command looking for data for Nany Zimmerman (ID Z005) would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE MemID = ‘Z005’
```

In the transactions list you also show the transaction description, which comes from the tblCodes table in the database.  The SQL for this operation is:

SELECT p.Memid, p.PurchaseDt, p.TransCd, c.TransDesc, p.TransType, p.Amount
FROM tblpurchases p, tblcodes c
WHERE p.TransCd = c.TransCd AND p.MemId = 'member id'
ORDER BY p.MemId, p.PurchaseDt, p.TransCd

Comment: Well, I'm running this in Netbeans 8.2 w/ JDK 8.211, the MySQL version installed is 2.7.25.0. Hope that helps?

Comment: Yes, @Mike - that helps a great deal! Always provide this kind of level of information about your environment, when you ask a question on SO ! Cheers !